# Storing dynamic id for TD ID with JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Okay, so i am pulling data from a json file and at the same time i am putting them in to a table. I've managed to give every td item a dynamic id. However, that id is only accessible inside the html and when i try to use for a function it is either undefined or it is getting the length of every row but not the id.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var dynID;

$(function() {

var data = [];

    $.getJSON( 'f-data.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.data, function(i, f) {
   var tblRow = "<tr><th>" + '<td id = "editable'+this.id+'">' + f.Title+ "</td></th>";

     dynID = $(this).find("td").attr("id");
    tblRow += '<th colspan="2"><button type ="submit" class="edit" onclick="editButton(dynID)"></i></button>';


   $(tblRow).appendTo(".screens tbody");

});

});

});

<script type='text/javascript'>
function editButton(id) {

    alert(id);

}
```

JSON :

```
{ "data":[
  {
   "Title": "Screen 1",
    "id": 1
 },{
   "Title": "Screen 2",
   "id": 2
 }
```

The above produces a button and when the button is pressed the result is undefined. The strange thing is that the id's are generated correctly (e.g. editable1, editable2, etc). I guess am not selecting the id correctly?

Comment: You have referencing issue. Can you post a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into reference issues within the `$.each` loop. Within the loop, the reference to `$(this)` is a jQuery object made of the element of `data` array. It does not have any HTML. I believe you meant to treat/parse `tblRow` as jQuery object and extract the `id` from it. Doing this is bad for performance. your current code simply the output of the button is:

```
<button onclick="editButton(dynID)"></button>
```

This is because `dynID` is becoming a part of the string -- there is no concatenating happening here. Hence, the output becomes a reference to a variable named `dynID` in the global scope `window`.

I would rewrite that code as below.

```
$.each(data.data, function(i, f) {

   var id = this.id, // use id accross the loop.
       tblRow = "<tr><th>" + '<td id = "editable' + id +'">' + f.Name + "</td></th>";

   tblRow += '<th colspan="2"><button type ="submit" class="edit" onclick="editButton("' + id + '")"></i></button>';

   $(tblRow).appendTo(".screens tbody");

});
```

Comment: I see the code changing correctly but i am getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } error...any thoughts?

Comment: Would like to refer me to a fiddle where this problem happens? :)